# Can I generate native code with LLVM as my compiler's backend?

Tags: compiler-construction, llvm

I am going to use LLVM as my compiler's backend. Is there any possibility to emit pure native code using LLVM or should I write the machine code generator?

Comment: "pure native code" -- as opposed to what? Of course you can emit native code (that's one of the purposes of LLVM). Use LLVM MCJIT, for example (given you want to JIT-compile).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to [write your own back end](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMBackend.html) for the target machine, unless there already is one.